# Adding span class for variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking at a JS file from a colleague who has since left my work place so have no access to them.

```
//populate the inheritance table but remove all rows first
$("#reportBeneficiariesTable tbody").html("");

$(".saved-beneficiary").each(function() {
        $( "#reportBeneficiariesTable tbody" ).append( "<tr style=\"height:40px\">" + 
        "<td>"+$(this).find(".name").html()+"</td>" +
        "<td>"+$(this).find(".relation").html()+"</td>" +
        "<td>"+$(this).find(".inheritanceVal").html()+"</td>" +
        "<td>"+$(this).find(".taxableInheritance").html()+"</td>" +
        "<td>€"+$(this).find(".taxLiability").html()+"</td>");
```

I am trying to use the variable for .name as a span class to bring in the input Name further down the page? I thought this could be achieved by this:

```
 $('.name-1').html(name);
```

But doesn't seem to work? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you want exactly? Could you describe the desired output?

Comment: I would like to be able to take the value that is input in the <td>         "<td>"+$(this).find(".name").html()+"</td>" . Which is a Name and output it in a sentence in the page for example, <span class="name-1"></span> is my name.

Answer (score 1):

You may use CSS as well. If you are allowed to use CSS you may transform the table's rows into flexbox and change the order of the `<td>`s inside, for example like this:

```css
table *{border:1px solid #d9d9d9;padding:.5em;}

table{display:block;}
table tr{display:flex;}
.name{order:1}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="name">name</td>
<td class="relation">relation</td>
<td class="inheritanceVal">inheritanceVal</td>
<td class="taxableInheritance">taxableInheritance</td>
<td class="taxLiability">taxLiability</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I wouldn't be too confident replacing the previous javascript in case it affects something elsewhere.

Comment: How can I then call the span for name elsewhere. I have replaced the table with your example and get the output I have entered earlier in the form, but when i try <span class=name"> it won't work?

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand you. You don't have a `<span class=name">` you have a `<td class="name">`. You may call it by it's class or by it's position in the markup. Please add an example of what you want to do

Comment: If I have that table above. I would like for a sentence below to say.
My name is John and my relation is Child.  The 'John' and 'Child' would be taken from the table. If that makes sense

Comment: [conye9980](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7302716/conye9980) This is an entirely different question. If you liked my previous answer please accept it and ask a new question